# Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user

Tags: php, mysql

Почему выводится вот это в браузере, в чем ошибка?

> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'Viktor'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in Z:\path\to\code.php on line 3

Comment: Предупреждение: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: доступ запрещён для пользователя 'Viktor'@'localhost' (использует пароль: ДА).


Какое слово вам непонятно?

Answer (score 3):

Нет доступа к базе данных. Надо проверить, правильные ли логин и пароль к базе данных.